# GroupBy in A set Of Array Elements using JavaScript (Easy Way to Group Based on Dynamic input of Headers)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create GroubBy for an array as shown below:

```
const sqlData = [
                ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g'],
                ['aa','10/11/2020','##',2,3,4,5],
                ['bb','10/12/2020','$$',23,13,14,95],
                ['aa','10/12/2020','!!',21,23,24,58],
                ['aa','10/12/2020','##',22,13,44,55],
                ['aa','10/11/2020','$$',12,33,45,52],
                ['bb','10/11/2020','!!',52,32,49,52],
                ['aa','10/11/2020','!!',72,53,44,51],
                ['bb','10/11/2020','##',12,3,43,65],
                ['bb','10/13/2020','##',112,63,4,85],
                ['bb','10/13/2020','$$',22,63,24,95],
                ['bb','10/12/2020','$$',32,73,44,50],
                ['bb','10/13/2020','$$',52,388,24,50],
                ['bb','10/13/2020','$$',72,233,41,52],
                ['bb','10/13/2020','##',82,123,46,57],
                ['bb','10/13/2020','!!',92,763,47,58],
               
            ];
```

So I have my sqlData[0] as `Table Header` and rest of the data as `Table Body`. I am interested in grouping by based on the third input which is `groupby headers` as shown below:

`groupbyheaders = [a,b,c]`

in a function `GenerateGroupByData(CurrentData,groupbyheaders,ops = sum)`. Where I have choices such as sum, average, max, min, etc.

How I procceed to solve this problem is through this:

- First Create Header Array which is `All Headers - Non Numeric Headers (where mathematical Op is not possible) + GroupByHeaders (that are Non Numeric)`

So in this case, it gives me:
`[a,b,c (which are groupby headers + non Numeric), d, e, f, g]`

Now I am performing a concatenation operation after looping through the entire initial data, which looks like this:
`aa<some unique token>10/11/2020<some unique token>##`

Now from all these values, I am generating unique entries and then based on those entries I am performing summation. Though I have done the ideation, scripting this is actually getting bigger and bigger and so I wanted all of yours inputs to do this task in a simplified and computation friendly way. THanks!

Comment: where is the code you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following. It uses ES6 syntax, but can easily be modified if you'd like.

```js
const sqlData = [
  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'],
  ['aa', '10/11/2020', '##', 2, 3, 4, 5],
  ['bb', '10/12/2020', '$$', 23, 13, 14, 95],
  ['aa', '10/12/2020', '!!', 21, 23, 24, 58],
  ['aa', '10/12/2020', '##', 22, 13, 44, 55],
  ['aa', '10/11/2020', '$$', 12, 33, 45, 52],
  ['bb', '10/11/2020', '!!', 52, 32, 49, 52],
  ['aa', '10/11/2020', '!!', 72, 53, 44, 51],
  ['bb', '10/11/2020', '##', 12, 3, 43, 65],
  ['bb', '10/13/2020', '##', 112, 63, 4, 85],
  ['bb', '10/13/2020', '$$', 22, 63, 24, 95],
  ['bb', '10/12/2020', '$$', 32, 73, 44, 50],
  ['bb', '10/13/2020', '$$', 52, 388, 24, 50],
  ['bb', '10/13/2020', '$$', 72, 233, 41, 52],
  ['bb', '10/13/2020', '##', 82, 123, 46, 57],
  ['bb', '10/13/2020', '!!', 92, 763, 47, 58],
];

// First, change the data to be an array of objects [{ column: value }]
const allColumns = sqlData.splice(0, 1)[0];
const sqlDataObjects = sqlData.map(row => {
  const result = {};
  allColumns.forEach(c => result[c] = row[allColumns.indexOf(c)]);
  return result;
});

// Dynamically create a mapping of method names to functions.
// All deal with an array and should return a single number.
const methods = {
  sum: (arr) => arr.reduce((total, v) => total + v, 0),
  avg: (arr) => methods.sum(arr) / arr.length,
};

function groupBy(columns, methodName) {
  const keyFn = (obj) => columns.map(c => obj[c]).join('<some unique token>');
  const result = {};

  // Create an object that just stores all raw values, grouped in arrays
  // (like ARRAY_AGG in PostgreSQL)
  const groups = sqlDataObjects.reduce((obj, row) => {

    // Construct a key and select all columns that we need to store in the result
    const key = keyFn(row);
    const aggregatedColumnKeys = allColumns.filter(k => !columns.includes(k));

    if (!(key in obj)) {
      obj[key] = {};
      aggregatedColumnKeys.forEach(c => obj[key][c] = []);
    }

    aggregatedColumnKeys.forEach(c => obj[key][c].push(row[c]));
    return obj;
  }, {});

  // Choose the method to apply
  const method = methods[methodName];

  // Apply the method to each column in each group
  Object.keys(groups).forEach(groupName => {
    const group = groups[groupName];
    result[groupName] = {};
    Object.keys(group).forEach(c => {
      result[groupName][c] = method(group[c]);
    });
  });

  return result;
}

console.log(groupBy(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'sum'));
console.log(groupBy(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'avg'));
```

Comment: Just a small doubt: `sum: (arr) => arr.reduce((sum, v) => sum + v, 0),` what does sum mean in the reduce function?

Comment: `sum` starts at 0 and then `v` is added to it every time. It's the running total, so you could also just call it `total`